# How to create two new columns based on previous rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have this table(sort by the **Date**):

```
  Hours Amount Date
1 2     20     1
2 1     20     3
3 6     20     10
4 3     20     20
```

And I want to create two new columns. Something like this

```
  Hours Amount Start End Time
1 2     20     20    18  1
2 1     20     18    17  3
3 6     20     17    11  10
4 3     20     11    7   20
```

**Start**:

> the first Start is the first **Amount**,
>
> the next one is based on the first **Amount** - **Hours**
>
> and so on

**End** is basically the next row for **Start**

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could use the `LAG` function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to use previous rows' values but you need SQL Server 2012 or later. What version are you using?

Comment: @MikeBruesch I am using microsoft sql server management studio 17

Comment: SSMS 2017 isn't a version of SQL Server, it's a version of SSMS (surprisingly). *What you have said would be akin to saying "Word 365" when asked what version of Windows you have.* You can get the version of SQl Server you have by running `PRINT @@VERSION;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a running `sum` to do this. Then a `lag` to get the previous `end` on to the current row.

```
select t.*,coalesce(lag(end) over(order by date),start) as start
from (select hours,amount,date,amount-sum(hours) over(order by date) as end
      from tbl
      ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply subtract the *Running Total* of those hours from the Amount:

```
select t.*
  ,amount - cumulative_hours as end
  ,amount - cumulative_hours + hours as start
from
 (
   select hours
     ,amount
     ,date
     ,sum(hours) over(order by date rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_hours
   from tab
  ) t
```